# Find date formats in a single date field

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find out how many different types of date formats are there in a single varchar column that stores date.

Entries are too many so can't do it manually.

Please suggest a SQL query to find different types of date formats present in the column with dates written with different formats.

Comment: A date has no format

Comment: True date/time fields store binary representations, they have no "formats". Formatting is only used when displaying and searching the field data, and in the latter case, parameterized queries can avoid formatting issues. If your field data has "formats", it sounds like it is probably being stored as strings instead of binary. In which case you are SOL unless you write a lot of parsing code.

Comment: I mean..like if in a database with date column "date" dates are stored as ....2016-08-31 & 2016-08-31 00:00:00  & more such formats...then how to find out formats

Comment: @JohnDoe which db you are using ?

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And please add the `create table` statement for the table in question. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I m using Oracle...and yes date is sorted as varchar

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: I think the answer is: you can't do that. How would you know which format e.g.:  `08/08/12` is? Is that `MM/DD/YY`? Is that `YY/MM/DD`?  Is that `YY/MM/DD`?

Comment: This is an excellent example on why you should **never** store dates in `varchar` columns

Comment: Actually it is the cross product of dd mm MI,yy yyyy rr,hh24,mon, mmm ss,tzr,tzh,tzm tzd,pm,-,/., ...  and some more

Comment: Check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country?wprov=sfla1

Comment: As well as the ambiguity already mentioned, would you count different separators as different formats? What about formats using month names in different languages? All you can do is try every date against every format you can think of/generate and count which ones get any hits (and how many, perhaps), but you can't get around the ambiguous formats so the answer will never be accurate. The only real answer is 'too many', which is an extension of it being the wrong data type. Why do you want/need to count them at all?

Answer (score 0):

You should create function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function f_invalid_date(date_field in varchar2,format_field in varchar2) return number as
  v_d date;
begin
  v_d := TO_DATE(date_field, format_field);
  return 0;
exception 
  when others then
    return 1;
end;
```

and you can control like this:

```
select
f_invalid_date(your_varchar_column/*'20160606'*/,'yyyymmdd' ) is_date_valid
from
your_table;
```

and if your `is_date_valid` column is **0** it is your valid for your sending format.

So you can try all date format  and count them.